# odoo doesn't restart after update

Tags: python, updates, odoo

I don't know where is the problem, but after an update, odoo doesn't want to restart

I have this :

```
sudo service odoo start
Starting odoo: ok

    http://myserver:8069 ==> nothing
```

I try this :

```
sudo service odoo stop
Stopping odoo: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 30691: No such process
ok
```

and

sudo service odoo restart
Restarting odoo: ok

==> I have on google chrome this message : fail connexion

If I do this : `top`

I have nothing on processus.

If I look my log I have this :

```
tail -f odoo-server.log
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/odoo'
2015-05-12 00:19:46,092 8451 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown
2015-05-12 00:19:46,092 8451 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown
```

If I edit my odoo-server.log

```
    2015-05-10 11:28:04,911 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:04] "POST /web/webclient/version_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:05,253 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:05] "POST /web/session/get_session_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:06,101 5121 INFO odoo openerp.service.common: successful login from 'loic.richard@e-imaginis.com' using database 'odoo'
2015-05-10 11:28:06,103 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:06] "POST /web/session/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:06,519 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:06] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:07,953 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:07] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:10,505 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:10] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 11:28:11,100 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [10/May/2015 11:28:11] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 12:33:03,551 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.249.80.126 - - [10/May/2015 12:33:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-10 12:33:04,044 5121 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.249.80.118 - - [10/May/2015 12:33:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-05-10 19:57:55,248 5121 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown
2015-05-10 19:57:55,249 5121 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
2015-05-10 19:58:04,512 24319 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0-20150510
2015-05-10 19:58:04,512 24319 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
2015-05-10 19:58:04,512 24319 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2015-05-10 19:58:04,512 24319 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2015-05-10 19:58:04,512 24319 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2015-05-10 19:58:04,722 24319 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2015-05-11 00:33:19,782 24319 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2015-05-11 00:33:20,381 24319 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2015-05-11 00:33:20,641 24319 INFO ? openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2015-05-11 00:33:20,651 24319 INFO odoo openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2015-05-11 00:33:20,659 24319 INFO odoo openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2015-05-11 00:33:20,677 24319 INFO odoo openerp.modules.loading: loading 46 modules...
2015-05-11 00:33:20,681 24319 INFO odoo passlib.registry: registered crypt handler 'pbkdf2_sha512': <class 'passlib.handlers.pbkdf2.pbkdf2_sha512'>
2015-05-11 00:33:20,681 24319 INFO odoo passlib.registry: registered crypt handler 'md5_crypt': <class 'passlib.handlers.md5_crypt.md5_crypt'>
2015-05-11 00:33:20,766 24319 INFO odoo openerp.modules.loading: 46 modules loaded in 0.09s, 0 queries
2015-05-11 00:33:21,449 24319 INFO odoo openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2015-05-11 00:33:21,451 24319 INFO odoo openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2015-05-11 00:33:21,607 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.102.6.237 - - [11/May/2015 00:33:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 00:33:22,117 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.102.6.237 - - [11/May/2015 00:33:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-05-11 11:28:14,354 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:14] "POST /web/webclient/version_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:14,746 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:14] "POST /web/session/get_session_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:15,617 24319 INFO odoo openerp.service.common: successful login from 'loic.richard@e-imaginis.com' using database 'odoo'
2015-05-11 11:28:15,620 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:15] "POST /web/session/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:16,889 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:16] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:17,894 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:17] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:20,577 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:20] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 11:28:21,031 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 11:28:21] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 20:47:16,435 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.102.6.253 - - [11/May/2015 20:47:16] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-05-11 23:52:50,600 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:51,104 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:51] "GET /web/css/web.assets_common/ceba8ad HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:51,222 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:51] "GET /logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:51,296 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:51] "GET /web/css/website.assets_frontend/f563fe5 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:51,537 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:51] "GET /web/js/web.assets_common/ceba8ad HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:51,545 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:51] "GET /web/js/website.assets_frontend/f563fe5 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:52,752 24319 INFO ? werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:52] "GET /website/static/src/xml/website.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:52,813 24319 INFO ? werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:52] "GET /website/static/src/img/library/business_stats.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-05-11 23:52:53,851 24319 INFO odoo werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [11/May/2015 23:52:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-05-12 00:02:22,536 24319 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown
2015-05-12 00:02:22,536 24319 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
2015-05-12 00:04:04,305 8451 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0-20150510
2015-05-12 00:04:04,356 8451 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
2015-05-12 00:04:04,356 8451 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2015-05-12 00:04:04,356 8451 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2015-05-12 00:04:04,357 8451 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2015-05-12 00:04:06,650 8451 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2015-05-12 00:10:05,444 8451 INFO ? werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [12/May/2015 00:10:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-05-12 00:10:05,456 8451 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
2015-05-12 00:10:05,456 8451 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 146, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/server.py", line 285, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1279, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1289, in load_addons
    for module in sorted(os.listdir(str(addons_path))):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0'
2015-05-12 00:10:06,322 8451 INFO ? werkzeug: 66.36.137.56 - - [12/May/2015 00:10:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-05-12 00:10:06,342 8451 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 146, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/server.py", line 285, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1280, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1391, in dispatch
    explicit_session = self.setup_session(httprequest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1312, in setup_session
    session_gc(self.session_store)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/func.py", line 41, in __get__
    value = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1265, in session_store
    path = openerp.tools.config.session_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/config.py", line 695, in session_dir
    os.makedirs(d, 0700)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/odoo'
```

If I remember I deleted in my opt, odoo directory

Is it the problem ?

I try to recreate the directory :

```
/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0
```

Doesn't work

maybe the problem come from the link ?

```
['/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons']
```

Do you have an idea ? what can I do ?

To contiue my discussion

I try this :

```
    ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons /opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0
sudo service restart
```

doesn't work

and finally this

```
root@.......:/opt# apt-get install odoo
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  odoo
1 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 48,8 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 1 024 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Réception de : 1 http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/deb/ ./ odoo 8.0.20150513 [48,8 MB]
48,8 Mo réceptionnés en 0s (49,8 Mo/s)
Lecture des fichiers de modifications (« changelog »)... Terminé 
(Lecture de la base de données... 81772 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du remplacement de odoo 8.0.20150512 (en utilisant .../odoo_8.0.20150513_all.deb) ...
Stopping odoo: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 3316: No such process
ok
Dépaquetage de la mise à jour de odoo ...
Paramétrage de odoo (8.0.20150513) ...
```

doesn't work also

and finally I tried this :

```
sudo service odoo stop
Stopping odoo: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 3491: No such process
ok
```

Nobody has been this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The line `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/odoo'` would seem to indicate that it's a filesystem permissions issue.  You mentioned that you deleted `/opt/odoo`, when it was recreated it likely didn't have the correct permissions for it to run.

Your odoo config file (commonly at `/etc/odoo-server.conf`) should have a line like `USER=odoo`, which is the local account that odoo will run under.  That account needs access to the `/opt/odoo` director and it's contents.

Running `chown odoo.odoo /opt/odoo -R` should provide permissions for the odoo account to work with the odoo directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont have permission to access that directory for that you can give permission to that directory 
For that got to that path through terminal and than follow this command

```
sudo chmod  777 -R //opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/(your folder name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new folder `/opt/odoo`, and then give permission to user odoo:

```
chown -R odoo:odoo /opt/odoo
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and I solved that.

Go to folder on your computer:

```
/etc
```

Then delete your odoo.

Comment: on mac press cmd + shift + g then write /etc and go